# how to specify particular record type of transaction search in netsuite...

Tags: netsuite

I want Salesorder records to my application.how to specify Salesorder recordtype to Transaction search Basic.currently i'm getting all types of records but i need only Sales order records...how to do please suggest me...

```
 SearchDateField created=new SearchDateField();
        //SearchDateFieldOperator searchDateFieldOperator=new SearchDateFieldOp;
        SimpleDateFormat dft1=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(fromDate);
        created.setSearchValue(calendar);
        Calendar calendar2=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTime(toDate);
        created.setSearchValue2(calendar2);
        created.setOperator(SearchDateFieldOperator.within);
        TransactionSearchBasic tsb=new TransactionSearchBasic();
        tsb.setDateCreated(created);

        SearchResult res = _port.search(tsb);
        RecordList rl=res.getRecordList();
        Record[] records=rl.getRecord();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you create a utility method like this:

```
public static SearchEnumMultiSelectField GetSearchEnumMultiSelectField(String[] searchValue, SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator op)
{
    SearchEnumMultiSelectField semsf = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
    semsf.operatorSpecified = true;
    semsf.@operator = op;
    semsf.searchValue = searchValue;
    return semsf;
}
```

and now during search you call it like this:

```
TransactionSearch ts = new TransactionSearch();
ts.basic = new TransactionSearchBasic();
ts.basic.type = GetSearchEnumMultiSelectField(new String[] { "salesOrder" }, SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf);

//Do rest of the code here for calling search

//Call Port.search etc
```

So the idea here is to use SearchEnumMultiSelectField object and set its different values to achieve your result.

Hope this helps!